# Triggering an airflow dag based on filesystem changes

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to write a pipeline where the postgres db should update with contents of a csv when it is brought to the folder. I have written a dag which creates the table and pushes the csv content when it is triggered from the web UI. Here's the code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule
from airflow.operators.postgres_operator import PostgresOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
import psycopg2

with DAG('Write_data_to_PG', description='This DAG is for writing data to postgres.', 
    schedule_interval='*/5 * * * *',
         start_date=datetime(2018, 11, 1), catchup=False) as dag:
    create_table = PostgresOperator(
        task_id='create_table',
        sql="""CREATE TABLE users(
            id integer PRIMARY KEY,
            email text,
            name text,
            address text
        )
        """,
    )

    def my_func():
        print('Pushing data in database.')
        conn = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=testdb user=testuser")
        print(conn)

        cur = conn.cursor()
        print(cur)

        with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
            next(f)  # Skip the header row.
            cur.copy_from(f, 'users', sep=',')

        conn.commit()
        print(conn)
        print('DONE!!!!!!!!!!!.')


    python_task = PythonOperator(task_id='python_task', python_callable=my_func)

    create_table >> python_task
```

I am not able to figure out how to trigger the tasks when the csv is pasted/brought manually to the folder.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create one DAG which periodically checks if any new file is moved to the folder and then trigger another DAG from there if any files are been moved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out Airflow has a special module just for such requirement. I solved the problem using FileSensor provided by airflow itself.

According the doucmentation:

> FileSensor Waits for a file or folder to land in a filesystem.
> If the path given is a directory then this sensor will only return true if
> any files exist inside it (either directly, or within a subdirectory)

Here is the modified code, it waits for the file called ***test.csv*** and it proceeds to the next task only when it finds the file in the airflow folder (or any folder, you need to specify the path):

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.sensors.file_sensor import FileSensor
from airflow.operators.postgres_operator import PostgresOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
import psycopg2

with DAG('Write_data_to_PG', description='This DAG is for writing data to postgres.', schedule_interval='*/5 * * * *',
         start_date=datetime(2018, 11, 1), catchup=False) as dag:
    create_table = PostgresOperator(
        task_id='create_table',
        sql="""CREATE TABLE users(
            id integer PRIMARY KEY,
            email text,
            name text,
            address text
        )
        """,
    )


    def my_func():
        print('Creating table in database.')
        conn = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=testdb user=testuser")
        print(conn)

        cur = conn.cursor()
        print(cur)

        with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
            next(f)  # Skip the header row.
            cur.copy_from(f, 'users', sep=',')

        conn.commit()
        print(conn)
        print('DONE!!!!!!!!!!!.')


    file_sensing_task = FileSensor(task_id='sense_the_csv',
                                   filepath='test.csv',
                                   fs_conn_id='my_file_system',
                                   poke_interval=10)

    python_task = PythonOperator(task_id='populate_data', python_callable=my_func)

    create_table >> file_sensing_task >> python_task
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for file system write events.

For a lower level Linux check out inotify: https://pypi.org/project/inotify/

For a higher level implementation that also works on Mac or windows: https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/

The idea is to add event watchers/event handlers that pick up on file/directory modifications. The event will contain the file path of the newly created/modified file.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer! Watchdog helped me listen to the file changes but I was unable to figure out how to trigger the dag when filesystem returned true for that file. I ultimately solved it using the FileSensor provided by airflow.

Comment: @YudhishthirSingh good to hear, I wasn't aware of the FileSensor so TIL something new ;)